# Java applet compatibility with IE8 security feature

Tags: java, security, memory, internet-explorer-8

We have a memory intensive java applet that runs in IE.   The client is trying to upgrade to IE8.   They want to enable the security feature Enable memory protection to help mitigate online attacks.   But when they do and try to access our application, they get the following error message:  "– “Internet Explorer has stopped trying to restore the website.  It appears the site continues to have a problem."   With the feature unchecked in IE8, the application works.     The client would like to keep the feature enabled on their browsers and are asking us if there is something we can do to allow this?

Has anyone run into this issue and if so, is there a way to allow the memory protection feature of IE8 to remain in place without crashing a Java applet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just did a work arround by including our application server as one of the IE trusted sites.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to Java [bug 6674383](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6674383), which was apparently fixed in 1.6.12. What Java version is the customer running?

Comment: Using JRE version 1.6.0_18-b07